# Eclipse cash project and not see code changes

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to make changes in java code but Eclipse not see it. For example i says:

```
System.out.println("WKT");
```

And exspect to see:

```
 WKT
```

But not see it.
10 minutes ago all works fine.  Now i see strange project icon in project manager:

[image]

Whats can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project is not getting compiled. I can see some errors in the projects. Some dependent project might be throwing error due to which it is not getting compiled.

Try fixing those errors, clean your project and then you should be able to see the desired output

Your code may not have any error but the project is compiled as a whole.

In case, it is not successfully compiled, the output will be of an old class version i.e. you cannot see any changes you make in the code.

Try 
Eclipse : Window -> Show View -> Problems. You will see all the problems in a window and you can fix them one by one

Comment: I make a clean and now i get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError is generated because Class definition is not available at runtime.  

Did you tried fixing the compilation errors first as the project shows a red symbol which shows that there is some errors in the project

Comment: Your code may not have any error but the project is compiled as a whole. In case, it is not successfully compiled you will see the old class version. On Eclipse : Window -> Show View -> Problems. You will see all the problems in a window and you can fix them one by one.

Comment: There are some classes with errors in `NoGDAL` project but now eclipse not show errors in them.

Comment: In problems tab i not see any promlems in project `NoGDAL`.

Comment: Right click on project : Build path -> configure build path -> java build path -> Projects (Tab). You will see the list of dependent projects. Try fixing errors in those projects

Comment: Its empty. Not see any dapendents.(

Comment: Sorry i find problem. `Build path -> configure build path -> java build path ->Libraries`. I delete library from project but its not deleted from build path.

Comment: Good. Now you must've got some idea of handling projects in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Project - Clean
```

and the select projects to rebuild

Comment: i try i and get after debug: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Read
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Read`

Comment: how about `gis-mrsk-portlet` project? it is not compilable, anything depends on it?

Comment: `gis-mrsk-portlet` works fine. Its contais just class wiht errors but it not used.

Comment: so disable that class from build path

Comment: But now i work with project `NoGDAl`. Or another project can have influens on debug other project?

Comment: It might if NOGDA1 has dependencies. Where class Read is located, btw?

Comment: class `Read` located in `NoGDAL` deafult package.